# Calculating numbers from fields in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm building a database for a baseball team, and one of the tables is for pitching stats. If you know baseball, you know baseball ERA is calculated as (number of earned runs given up / divided by innings pitched) * 9.

In the table, I have separate columns for Innings Pitched, and for Earned Runs, and through an SQL statement, i want to calculate the ERA

Currently Innings Pitched is stored as a decimal, like "1.0" or "6.1", or "7.2", something like that, however when calculated, if there is a decimal (like "7.2"), I need the ".2" to actually change to ".66666", or a ".1 to change to ".33333".

Here is what I have tried so far in my SQL:

```
    SELECT *, CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), ((stat_er / NULLIF(stat_ip,0)) * 9)) AS stat_era FROM stats_pitching ORDER BY stat_era ASC
```

This  does the "stat_ip" as ".0", ".1" or ".2", as that is how it is from the database. How could I change anything in the column ending in ".1" or ".2" to ".3333" or ".6666" respectively in the SQL equation? Would I use a "Case" type, and if so, does anyone have some examples?

Comment: how can 7.666666 really mean 7.2 ??? 7.2 really means 7.2 period, it can be a rounded up or rounded down value of infinite numbers.  i.e 7.1676 ,  7.178 , 7.1989234324234324 anything like I said infinite numbers.

Comment: It's pretty common in American baseball statistics to use .1 and .2 to represent one-third and two-thirds of an inning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that applying simple math, using `ROUND` function. Lets say `Value` is your column name.

```
ROUND(Value, 0) + (10 * (Value - ROUND(Value, 0)) / 3)
```

Little demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5ad7f/2

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE` as below:

```
declare @x decimal(38,6) = 7.1

select case @x - cast(FLOOR(@x) as decimal)
    when 0 THEN @x
    when 0.1 THEN cast(FLOOR(@x) as decimal) + 0.3333
    when 0.2 THEN cast(FLOOR(@x) as decimal) + 0.6666
end
```

That will always turn

- x.0 to x.0
- x.1 to x.3333
- x.2 to x.6666

where x is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and solved it this way...

```
select CASE WHEN CAST(stat_ip as VARCHAR) like '%.1%' THEN stat_ip + .2333333 
            WHEN CAST(stat_ip as VARCHAR) like '%.2%' THEN stat_ip + .4666667 
            ELSE stat_ip
            END
from stats_pitching
```